# Using 'in' when the object may be a string

Tags: javascript

I was looking up how to check if a variable in JavaScript is an array, but then as the SO page was loading, I thought of a solution to the problem. Looking through the answers, I found that none of them had thought of this simple answer: Just check for the methods we need to use on the array, so that it still works for any user defined types that implement the same methods. Being the helpful person I am, I thought I'd submit my answer for future people trying to solve the same problem..But after testing it, I found it does not work.

```
function print(object) {
  if ('map' in object) { // If the object implements map, treat it like an array
    object.map(function(current) {
      console.log(current);
    });
  } else {               // Otherwise, treat it as a string
    console.log(object);
  }
}
```

Now, this works fine when I call it with an array, but if I use a string it fails. Since strings are objects in javascript, why shouldn't the 'in' keyword work for them? Is there any way to implement this that is as simple as what it currently is?

Comment: Do this: `if ("map" in Object(object)) {...` Any primitive will be converted to its object wrapper type.

Comment: ^^This is simple, I like it.

Comment: I must say though that there are more reliable was to see if an object is an Array.

Comment: But as long as they implement map, should I really care if it actually  is an array?

Comment: Depends on what the `.map` that is found is and does. You're assuming it'll be a function. And even if it is, it could be a function that does something unexpected. Probably not likely though.

Comment: If you're really just trying to see if it's an array, why not just use `Array.isArray()` (or its polyfill) and avoid this whole `"map" in x` fiasco.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the property and test its type:

```
if (object != null && typeof object.map === 'function')
    object.map(...);
// ...
```

---

> Since strings are objects in javascript, why shouldn't the 'in' keyword work for them?

Not quite. There is a difference between a [primitive string value](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.16) and a [`String` instance object](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.18).

```
typeof "foo";        // "string"
typeof new String(); // "object"
```

Primitive values don't have properties themselves, which is why the `in` operator throws an `Error` when used on them. They will, however, be temporarily boxed into Objects by property accessors:

```
var a = "foo";
a.bar = 'bar';      // no error, but...
console.log(a.bar); // undefined

String.prototype.baz = function () {
    return this + this;
};

console.log(a.baz()); // "foofoo"
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could do something like this:

```
var y = function (o) {
    if (typeof o != "string" && "map" in o)
        console.log("not a string"); //your code here
    else
        console.log("It's a string!"); //your code here
}
```

I tested this with `var x = "hello"` and it worked. Because `&&` short circuits in JavaScript, it will stop at `typeof o != "string"`, which is good, since `"map" in o` fails for `string`s. Note the intentional use of lowercase, which is for primitives; `String`s are objects. I'm not exactly sure if this is what you were aiming for.